# Redirecting Angular routes to Django

Tags: angularjs, django, angular

Question:
What is best way to serve routes when you need to serve some URLs from Angular, and some from Django Templates

---

**Details:**

We are planning to move from Django Templates to Angular.

We are planning to migrate feature by feature rather than at one go.

Initially, the plan is:

1. Hit Angular routes
2. Angular check whether it is part of Angular route
3. Else, it passes the URL to Django which returns the result.

Here, 3rd point seems tricky to me and may result in recursion, since any redirect I write may simply start from step 1.

Other plans which we consider:

1. Route all URLs through the proxy server, which matches routes and then decides whether to redirect to Django and Angular. I am not very keen on it since we need to duplicate (and then maintain) either Angular or Django URLs. We would need to remember and update the URL scheme at two places
2. Change URL scheme to differentiate between Angular and Django apps, for example: www.example.com/angular/  vs www.example.com/rest-of-url. Then use Gateway API which serves the page on basis of URL. The reason we don't like it is that it breaks existing URLs. Customers who are using www.example.com/home now may need to visit www.example.com/angular/home. Plus, it seems aesthetically ugly.

---

Comment: Did you find any way to do it? is it possible?